# Using Java, How do I instantiate GAE Datastore so that it can be used in conjunction with GqlQuery?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, constructor, google-cloud-datastore, gql

Good day all, I am working with Google App Engine on a project that stores and retrieves data from the cloud Datastore. Adding the data and writing it has been no problem, but retrieving it using GqlQueries has proven difficult. The issue I am having is this: I am unable to instantiate the Datastore object in a way that will allow me to use it with GQL. I think the issue has to do with using the wrong imports. Here is some of my code:

.

```
    import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
    import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;
    import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key;
    import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;
    import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyFactory;
    import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.Filter;
    import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.*;

    import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.FilterPredicate;
    import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.FilterOperator;
    import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.CompositeFilter;
    import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.CompositeFilterOperator;
    import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query;
    import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PreparedQuery;

    import com.google.apphosting.datastore.DatastoreV4.EntityResult;
    import com.google.apphosting.datastore.DatastoreV4.GqlQuery;
    import com.google.apphosting.datastore.DatastoreV4.PropertyFilter;
    import com.google.apphosting.datastore.DatastoreV4.RunQueryRequest;
    import com.google.apphosting.datastore.DatastoreV4.RunQueryResponse;

            //Build a Query
            GqlQuery.Builder query = GqlQuery.newBuilder().setQueryString("SELECT * FROM Person");
            RunQueryRequest request = RunQueryRequest.newBuilder().setGqlQuery(query).build();

            RunQueryResponse response = datastore.runQuery(request);
            List<Entity> results = new ArrayList<Entity>();
            for (EntityResult entityResult : response.getBatch().getEntityResultList()) {
              results.add(entityResult.getEntity());
            }

    /* This is the Datastore object I was initializing. It initializes just fine but
    it cannot invoke the runQuery(request) method; nor will it allow me to add items to the 
list of entities, keeps saying that they are not of similar type. 
    */
    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
```

With with screen shot, you can see there are many different options for imports and it seems like no matter which one I choose it causes problems of some sort. 
[image]
.

This popup appears over any of the imports that use repackaged: "Use of com.google.appengine.repackaged may result in your app breaking without warning."

Anyone have any recommendations as to how to fix this problem? Which imports to use? Or any tutorial I can follow on the subject? I would appreciate it. Thanks!

-Sil

Comment: I know its not a solution, but have you considered using some sort of framework on top of the datastore? Maybe objectify?

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation [1] you might need to use this import:

```
import static com.google.apphosting.client.datastoreservice.client.DatastoreHelper.*;
```

Although, it seems that GQL is more supported for Python than for Java. Most documentation about GQL is written for Python and there is no specific reference for it on the JAVA section [2] but  for the analogue section of Python GQL is referenced [3].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/gql

[2] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries

[3] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#gql